# SIGSEGV when using native library on android, hardware accelerated only

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using the [Superpowered SDK](http://superpowered.com/) to do some audio playback and recording. When I press a button to start playback the app crashes with

```
A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
A/DEBUG: pid: 18529, tid: 18548, name: RenderThread  >>> com.superpowered.example <<<
A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f789f8000  x1   0000007f7409f288  x2   0000007f7d6a8a88  x3   0000000000fe502b
A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000116906  x5   0000000000000000  x6   00000a4cc0b1813f  x7   0000007f789f8000
A/DEBUG:     x8   000000000055655a  x9   000000000055655a  x10  000000000000a8c0  x11  00000000213b09a0
A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000018  x13  ffffffffa82de1ea  x14  000bb95f86000000  x15  003b9aca00000000
A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f7dadc7d8  x17  0000007f7d6a8a54  x18  0000007f78892ee8  x19  0000007f78891000
A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f7409f288  x21  0000007f78892ee8  x22  0000007f7bf4e000  x23  0000007f7bf4e000
A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f7409f288  x25  7fffffffffffffff  x26  00000000ffffffff  x27  0000007f7a52a9b0
A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007f635331e0  x29  0000007f7409f190  x30  0000007f7bec3840
A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f7409f190  pc   0000007f7bec3850  pstate 0000000080000000
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000025850  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000026e5c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000026fd8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000002b43c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+124)
A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000001579c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+208)
A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000903cc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+96)
A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000014fec  /system/lib64/libutils.so
A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000065fb4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+52)
A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000001ed84  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

I already opened an issue on their github repo, but they won't investigate any further bacause it's obviously an error in my "custom UI code".

So after hours of debugging here is what I found:

- It seems like triggering playback in the native library somehow interferes with the android internals.
- Adding random delays to the button actions reduces the likelihood of a crash.
- A temporary workaround was to disable hardware acceleration (`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`).

If you want to try it yourself you can find the code [here](https://github.com/fl0cke/SuperpoweredExample). 
Has anyone had a similiar problem? Is there any workaround that doesn't involve disabling HW acceleration? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79312 The last comment looks like it may be you, so apologies if this is old news. Anyway, some people are saying it's fixed in recent versions of Android. What API level are you running?

Comment: @FrancescaNannizzi Thanks for pointing out, but yes, that is indeed me in the last comment... I can see at least one other person in that thread with the same crash on Android 6.01. So what do you mean with recent versions? I'm compiling with target sdk version 23.

Comment: By recent versions, I mean recent releases of the Android OS. You can target an SDK version number that is different than the actual OS running on your device. What OS version number is running on your device?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437017 In this thread on the same stack trace, it seems like the issue went away for OS versions later that 5.1. Unfortunately, I haven't seen any conclusive responses from Google about an actual resolution for the problem, so this is all conjecture.

Comment: @FrancescaNannizzi I'm running Android 6.0.1 and I also tested it on a device running 6.0.2. I think it's safe to call that a recent version.

Comment: Yep, looks like it won't be that easy.

Comment: Yeah, still thanks for your efforts.